# Unattended Apt-get upgrade does nothing

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

I'm trying to create a script that updates my Ubuntu installation at shutdown.

To upgrade my system I use the following command:

`unbuffer apt-get full-upgrade -y --allow-downgrades --show-progress 2>&1 > /var/log/ubuntu-automatic-update/update_status.txt`

But when it's executed, the log shows the following:

```
Package lists are read... 0%

Package lists are read... 100%

Package lists are read... Done

Dependency tree is built... 0%

Building dependency tree... 0%

Building dependency tree... 50%

Building dependency tree... 50%

Dependency tree is built... Done

Status information is read in... 0%

Status information is read in... 0%

Status information is read in... Done
0 updated, 0 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 168 not updated.
```

But running the exact same command manually in terminal updates everything.
Though, it then tells me that 5 packages would be newly installed.

Can this somehow be fixed that it updates anyway?

Edit: The complete script can be found here: https://github.com/TobiPeterG/ubuntu_automatic_updates/edit/main/files/shutdown_update
maybe I did an error in there?

Comment: Rather than re-create the wheel, consider using the existing option for update-at-shutdown for security upgrades and kernel upgrades located at `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`. Personally, I would not run a full-upgrade unattended.

Comment: *"168 not updated"* - Why would you attempt to create an automated script when you are so far behind on maintenance?  I agree that your plan is a bad one and also confused why you are so far behind on updates.